# Issue with mysqli in PHP Warning: mysqli_stmt_prepare() expects parameter 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I have been looking at this code for a while and can't figure out where the problem is.

I am new to coding in general, but especially new to `CRUD` and `SQL`. I want to create a prepared statement here to use variables instead of exact values. I don't understand where the issue comes from

I have a Databasetools.php

```
<?php
class DatabaseTools
{
    //private $user = $_SESSION['userId']; // these get called when the object gets created
    //private $userEmail = $_SESSION['emailUser'];

    public function __construct($Name)
    {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $dBUsername = "root";
        $dBPassword = "supersecretpassword";
        $dbPort = "3306";

        $this->name = $Name;
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $this->name, $dbPort);
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if(!$conn)
        {
            die("connection faild: ".mysqli_connect_error()); 
        }
    }

    public function lookup($dBName, $Row, $Column)
    {
        //$sql = "SELECT ".$Column." FROM ".$dBName." WHERE ".$Row.";";
        $sql = "SELECT ? FROM ? WHERE ?;";
        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql))
        {
            echo "False";
        }
        else 
        {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $column, $dBName, $Row);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            echo $result;
        }
        // try to connect to the database
    }
    public function setCell($Database, $Row, $Column)
    {

    }

    public function disconnect($dBName)
    {

    }
    public function echotest()
    {

    }
}
?>
```

And I am using a page to check if the code is working

```
<?php
require "Model/php/databaseTools.php";

$loginData = new databaseTools("loginsystem");
$loginData->lookup("loginsystem","*","*");
?>
```

Thanks so much if you could point me in the write direction.

Comment: You can only parameterize values, not columns, tables, functions, etc. Please add the full error to the question and show which line it references.

Comment: You also cannot parametrize any SQL syntax. Also `...WHERE *` isn't a valid syntax.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_stmt_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in databaseTools.php on line 27
False

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have $stmt value in the lookup function?

Try to add it as one of the parameters, something like this:

```
public function lookup($dBName, $stmt, $Row, $Column)
```

and then call it also with `$stmt` parameter:

```
$loginData->lookup("loginsystem", <stmt> ,"*","*");
```

Comment: I have the statement value as the constructor. Does this not work? should i put it as a public variable outside the constructor?